# Problema al recuperar datetime

Tags: mysql, nodejs, mysql-workbench

Tengo un problema al recuperar las fecha en mi API Rest.

Inserto un dato y se rellena automáticamente el datetime en mi BD.
por ejemplo.

`2017-09-27T23:16:46.000Z` este valor que se genera automáticamente y lo puedo ver con mysql workbench.

Pero cuando recupero con mi API que es una consulta tan básica como esta:

```
select * from inv;
```

Me devuelve `2017-09-27T21:16:46.000Z` con dos horas menos que el valor de la base de datos.

¿Cual puede ser el problema?

Inserto dos imágenes para que veáis la tabla y la respuesta de la API.
[image: imagen Respuesta API]
[image: MySQL]

Un saludo y gracias.

EDIT:

Este es el código que utilizo para lanzar la petición a la BD:

```
    function getInvTop(req, res) {

        if (connection)
        {

            connection.query('SELECT * FROM invjuan WHERE attrName = "sensor2" ORDER BY recvTime DESC LIMIT 15', function(err, rows) {
                if(err)
                {
                    throw err;
                    console.log('Error al Conectar' + error);
                }
                else
                {
                    res.status(200).json(rows);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Para la respuesta por ahora solo llamo al método desde Postman.

Como cliente estoy utilizando `Angular4`, no se si lo correcto es formatear la fecha desde este.

Si lanzo esta consulta me da el siguiente error:

```
SELECT recvTimeTs, CONVERT_TZ('recvTime','GMT','MET'), fiwareServicePath, entityId, entityType, attrName, attrType, attrValue, attrMd FROM iof.invjuan WHERE attrName = "sensor2" ORDER BY recvTime DESC LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código donde manejas la respuesta de la API para mostrarla en pantalla?

Comment: Edito el post y pongo el codigo @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas Manolait,

Parece ser que tu problema viene relacionado con las fechas UTC, me explico.

Al parecer, tu Mysql Workbench se encarga de convertir tu fecha automáticamente a la fecha de tu TimeZone (hora del pc), pero el valor real que tienes en la base de datos es `2017-09-27T23:16:46.000Z` (UTC), entonces a la hora de hacer tu el `select * from inv` desde tu aplicación, te devuelve la hora en UTC y tienes que aplicar tu el cambio a la TimeZone.

Intuyo por la diferencia de fechas que nos muestras (2 horas) ahora mismo estás en `GMT +2`, es decir, Europe, entonces una solución a tu problema seria insertar lo siguiente en el select:

```
CONVERT_TZ(nombre_campo_fecha,'GMT','MET')
```

[Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

Comment: Buenas Marc, muchas gracias por la respuesta tiene toda la pinta de ser eso. si yo tengo esta consulta 'SELECT * FROM invjuan WHERE attrName = "sensor2" ORDER BY recvTime DESC LIMIT 15' ¿donde tengo que meter lo que has comentado?

Comment: Deberías hacer el `select` poniendo todos los campos manualmente en la instrucción, y no hacerlo con el `*`, o también podrías hacer un `select *` primero sin coger la fecha en el programa, y después hacer el `select` que te he propuesto y en este caso cogiendo la fecha.

Comment: Buenas, estoy probando con esta consulta SELECT recvTimeTs, CONVERT_TZ('recvTime','GMT','MET'), fiwareServicePath, entityId, entityType, attrName, attrType, attrValue, attrMd FROM iof.invjuan WHERE attrName = "sensor2" ORDER BY recvTime DESC LIMIT 15; pero me pone a nulo el campo recvTime, añado lo que muestra en el post.

Comment: Manolait, no pongas las comillas simples en el CONVERT_TZ: `CONVERT_TZ(recvTime,'GMT','MET')` sino le estas diciendo que te convierta el texto entre comillas a TimeZone. Yo he puesto las comillas para que entendieras, ahora lo edito.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo sin las comillas y nada sigue reemplazando la cabecera del campo por CONVERT_TZ(recvTime,'GMT','MET') y los campos a null

Comment: @Manolait Me acabo de fijar, si te fijas, en el manual pone que para usar 'MET' necesitas hacer unos pasos previos, si no quieres usar esto puedes usar directamente: `CONVERT_TZ(recvTime, '+00:00', '+02:00')` así lo conviertes al GMT +2.

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracia por la ayuda eso ya me funciona en MYSQL workbens, pero a la hora de poner la consulta en mi API con NODEJS me da este error:    connection.query('SELECT recvTimeTs, recvTime, CONVERT_TZ(recvTime, '+00:00', '+02:00'), fiwareServicePath, entityId, entityTy
pe, attrName, attrType, attrValue, attrMd FROM iof.invjuan WHERE attrName = "sensor2"', function(err, rows) {
                                                                                                              ^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)

Comment: Buenas @Marc, ya esta solucionado el problema,

muchas gracias. :D

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, Gracias a lo aportado por Marc, solucione el problema de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT recvTimeTs, CONVERT_TZ(recvTime, "+00:00", "+02:00") AS recvTime, fiwareServicePath, entityId, entityType, attrName, attrType, attrValue, attrMd FROM iof.invjuan WHERE attrName = "sensor1" ORDER BY recvTime DESC LIMIT 15
```

Muchas gracias.